# Do a simple apache server with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

i'm having an hard time to start learning kubernetes the documentations isn't really simple i want to realize simple trick for the moment i'm familliar with docker and i wan't to learn orchestration with kubernetes .
i've realized the following yml file :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  replicas: 1 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: ubuntu:20.04
        command: ["/scripts/ubuntu.sh"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
        volumeMounts:
        - name: scripts
          mountPath: /scripts
      volumes:
      - name: scripts
        configMap:
          name: scripts
          defaultMode: 0744
```

in my sh file i've got the following :

```
#!/bin/sh
apt install -y apache2 && service apache2 start && tail -f /dev/null
```

the idea is to launch an ubuntu , install apache2 , start the service , keep container alive with a tail , and being able to go on the mapped 80 port from container to my host .

i think i'm doing something wrong when i launch kubectl apply -f i get :
`deployment.apps/test-deployment created`
but nothing up on my localhost unfortunatly ...

anyone already had that problem ?

PS: i'm using docker desktop on windows .

Edit :

Now i got my pods running but i cannot access my apache on localhost:80 heres my actual config :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
  labels:
    app: apache
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  replicas: 1 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: ubuntu:20.04
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "apt update -y && apt install -y apache2 && service apache2 start && tail -f /dev/null"]
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: DEBIAN_FRONTEND
          value: noninteractive
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apache-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: apache
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30001
```

Comment: you should run `kubectl get pod -l app=test` to list the pod created for that deployment. Then you should check the logs of that pod using `kubectl logs $(kubectl get pod -l app=test -o name)`


then run a describe on the pod using `kubectl describe  $(kubectl get pod -l app=test -o name)`

Comment: the output of above commands should give you good idea what is going on, especially the `kubectl describe` one.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you would not typically install software into your container at runtime like this (neither in Kubernetes nor in Docker). A far more common and manageable approach is to build a custom image from a Dockerfile, and then use that image in your deployments. For this particular purpose, you would probably just start with the [official httpd image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd).

Comment: thanks @P.... i'll try those command and debug myself

Comment: yes @larsks you're absolutly right about the way to do it , but i'm doing this for practice i'm thinking about when i'll have to do some test inside container when all my containers up and are ready . maybe the best option is make an image with script test inside with dockerfile like you said and make a script that start with systemd ?

Comment: You would also not usually run systemd in a container: a container should have a single entrypoint so that your container orchestration system (docker or kubernetes) can handle things like restarting the containers when they fail.

Comment: @larsks okay , i found a way to launch my instruction like this on container starting  :
``
 command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "apt update -y && apt install -y apache2 && service apache2 start && tail -f /dev/null"] 

``
maybe not best practice i guess but it do the job

Answer (score 1):

Problem Fixed :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
  labels:
    app: apache
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  replicas: 1 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: ubuntu:20.04
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "apt update -y && apt install -y apache2 && service apache2 start && tail -f /dev/null"]
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: DEBIAN_FRONTEND
          value: noninteractive
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apache-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: test
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
    # nodePort: 30001
```

my problem was coming from the selector in service that i was using wrongly i'll check how it work exactly but now i'm having my service providing my ubuntu with apache on localhost perfectly .

Edit :
After checking i've uncomment the `selector: app : test` under spec service , because it wasn't working without it now everything ok !